# What is the difference between two code snippets

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to create a splash screen form. Its opacity value set to zero. And I have a timer named `tmrfadein`. Its interval is equal to 5.

If I use this code below then it works as expected, the splash form appears gradually.

```
if (Opacity == 1)
{
    tmrfadein.Enabled = false;
}

Opacity += 0.01;
```

If I use this code, splash screen appears without waiting

```
do
{
    Opacity += 0.01;
}

while (Opacity < 1);
tmrfadein.Enabled = false;
```

When I debug the code everything looks ok. What is wrong with second one?

Comment: What would it wait for? the second code just carries on updating opacity until it is 1+ and then continues with the rest of your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second example doesn't have any delay in the execution. The first example only increments the opacity value once then waits for the next timer job. The second example keeps incrementing until its value is one in the first timer job hence no delay. You could add a wait into your do while or just stick with the first example?

Answer (score 0):

The `do..while` loop runs to completion without updating the UI. You *need* a timer or something like that to show the animation.